# Check if Windows File Explorer is already opened in python

Tags: python, explorer

I have simple script that launches Windows File Explorer

```py
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["start", "explorer.exe"],shell=True)
```

I'd like to check if Windows File Explorer is already opened so that I don't open another instance. How can I do it? Solutions without external libraries are preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution

```py
import win32gui

explorerWindows = []

def handler( hwnd, list ):
  # only explorer windows have class 'CabinetWClass'
  if 'CabinetWClass' in win32gui.GetClassName(hwnd):
    list.append(hwnd)

win32gui.EnumWindows(handler, explorerWindows)

explorerOpened = len(explorerWindows) > 0
```

**EDIT: easier method**

```py
import win32gui
explorerOpened = win32gui.FindWindow('CabinetWClass', None) != 0
```

Comment: Can you also explain how/why this works? For example, what is `CabinetWClass`? (Please do not answer in comments but edit your answer)

Comment: (And maybe add a reference to documentation where you found this)

Comment: NB: Interesting related article: [Why does the class name for Explorer change depending on whether you open it with /e?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150619-00/?p=45341)